# Change sign in text in MS Teams search based messaging extension

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

```html
 def sign_in_response(self):
        data = {
            "composeExtension": {
                "type": "auth",
                "suggestedActions": {
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "openUrl",
                            "value": settings.LOGIN_PAGE,
                            "title": "Sign in to Sentieo"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
        return data
```

This is the response , i am using for sign in action,The "title" is changing the top line as shown in the screenshot.

[image: MS Teams search based messaging extension]

Is there any way to change the bottom text as well?
Instead of "You'll need to sign in to use this app."  -> "You'll need to sign in to use Sentieo App"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this text is not customizable. Could you please post feature suggestions on [Microsoft Teams feedback portal on UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)?